# ImportError: No module named wmicodes.makes

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am trying to setup my project in django and the folder structure seems to be fine. However upon running the command `python manage.py runserver` I get a ImportError: No module named wmicodes.makes.
So i went into the traceback and found out a few files which led me to it.
here are the files.

myfolder/myfolder/somename/models/base.py

```
#other imports
from wmicodes.makes import InternalMake # i get the error on this particular line
#other imports
'''The rest of the code'''
```

here's another file
myfolder/myfolder/somename/models/**init**.py

```
from .base import *
#other imports
```

and here's the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mayureshkadam/Desktop/myfolder/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mayureshkadam/Desktop/myfolder/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/mayureshkadam/Desktop/myfolder/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/home/mayureshkadam/Desktop/myfolder/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mayureshkadam/Desktop/myfolder/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/mayureshkadam/Desktop/myfolder/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/home/mayureshkadam/Desktop/myfolder/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/mayureshkadam/Desktop/myfolder/myfolder/somename/models/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .base import *
  File "/home/mayureshkadam/Desktop/myfolder/myfolder/somename/models/base.py", line 20, in <module>
    from wmicodes.makes import InternalMake
ImportError: No module named wmicodes.makes
```

I tried finding the error however failed. any pointers would be of help. thanks!

Comment: Is this `wmicodes` module added in installed apps in `settings.py`?

Comment: No it wasn't but what i did was i tracked InternalMake.py file and copied the absolute path and then included this file in the code..and it worked! @MKPatel

Comment: You can put answer whatever you did so, if anybody will face same issue then they will solve it by your answer.

Comment: I've posted the answer. do check!

Comment: It Looks Good :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i found out the answer by myself..I tried to located where internalmakes was and I got a python file, I copied the absolute path and included it in my code as

```
from absolute path import InternalMakes
```

and this one line solved my error.